# How to improve validation accuracy in training convolutional neural network?

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

I am training a CNN model(made using Keras). Input image data has around 10200 images. There are 120 classes to be classified. Plotting the data frequency, I can see that sample data for every class is more or less uniform in terms of distribution.

Problem I am facing is loss plot for training data goes down with epochs but for validation data it first falls and then goes on increasing. Accuracy plot reflects this. Accuracy for training data finally settles down at .94 but for validation data its around 0.08.

Basically its case of over fitting.

I am using learning rate of 0.005 and dropout of .25.

What measures can I take to get better accuracy for validation? Is it possible that sample size for each class is too small and I may need data augmentation to have more data points?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what could be the reason. First you can try classical regularization techniques like reducing the size of your model, adding dropout or l2/l1-regularizers to the layers. But this is more like randomly guessing the models hyperparameters and hoping for the best.

The scientific approach would be to look at the outputs for your model and try to understand why it produces these outputs and obviously checking your pipeline. Did you had a look at the outputs (are they all the same)? Did you preprocess the validation data the same way as the training data? Did you made a stratified train/test-split, i.e. keeping the class distribution the same in both sets? Is the data shuffles when you feed it to your model?

In the end you have about ~85 images per class which is really not a lot, compare CIFAR-10 resp. CIFAR-100 with 6000/600 images per class or ImageNet with 20k classes and 14M images (~500 images per class). So data augmentation could be beneficial as well.